# Value of global variable isn`t changing although its local value is changing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The value of the global variable `currentLength` is changed by entering different values to input. It is necessary that the value of the global variable `currentLength` be equal to the current value in input.

Entering the number 120, `alert` should work, it does not work, which means that the value of the global variable isn`t redefined.

```js
function getCurrentLength() {
  let currentLength = 0;
  let output = document.getElementById('output');

  calcLength();

  function calcLength() {
    let total = +output.value;
    let len = document.getElementsByClassName('len');
    for (let i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
      len[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
        let value = 0;
        currentLength = +len[i].value;
        for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
          let num = +len[j].value || 0;
          value += num;
        }
        output.value = total + value;
      })
    }
  }

  if (currentLength === 120) {
    alert(currentLength)
  }
}
getCurrentLength();
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="output">
```

I expect `currentLength` value is 120, but it`s all the time 0, be it alert or just using of`currentLength` value for further global operations, it makes nothing.

Comment: Your `if(currentLength === 120)` block runs exactly once at the very start, then never again. So even if `currentLength` ends up being 120, the alert won't show. `currentLength` does change its value all the time, it's always one digit behind what I type in the first input for instance. How is this supposed to work exactly? Is this about adding all input values together?

Comment: You also have two functions but you only call them once, which makes it kinda superfluous to have a function in the first place. I tried to clean up the code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rsdgc503/

Comment: I need current value (that is inside an event listener) to be assigned to global variable (that is outside of event listener). Value of global variable is used for further mathematical operations

Comment: What concerns the code above: 1. Result of all input values isn`t a current result, it summarizes all entered values between each other. 
2. I have several mathematical operations that have result used each for next mathematical operations, well, I do it using functions otherwise it will be very unstructured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: You check `currentLength === 120` once when calling `getCurrentLength`, but at that time, there is no `currentLength`, because `currentLength` only gets set when an input field changes.

Change your `currentLength === 120` check to be inside the event handler, then you will get the expected result:

```
// ...
output.value = total + value;
if (currentLength === 120) {
    alert (currentLength);
}
// ...
```

Comment: I need current value (that is inside an event listener) to be assigned to global variable (that is outside of event listener). Value of global variable is used for further mathematical operations, well, I need it anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are assigning the global variable. But your `if` check runs only once at the beginning, where it cannot be fulfilled yet. So either run it inside the event handlers, or add a button to run the check. With your current implementation, your `currentLength === 120` check will run once and fail.

Comment: My level isn't so good, but I guess that it can be possible to do with callbacks or maybe one more event handler, isn`t it?

Comment: When exactly do you want your alert to pop up? To understand your program flow, I will need more details.

Comment: 1. function `getCurrentLength()` is called
2. I can freely take value of `currentLength` for manipulations with it on the levels higher.

All full code, if you need, here - https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/MZWJjR
Code chaining there is: calcLength() is one of code samples that gives me needed parameter. There are several functions there with outputting parameters. Then, calling function `globalCalc()`, I get all parameters for further operations.